# Portlet doesn't get removed from site page in LIFERAY 6.1

Tags: liferay-6

I am using Liferay 6.1.

When I add a portlet after starting server, it goes fine.

Problem is, When I try to remove it by clicking the 'x' icon on top-right, it gets removed.

But, after refreshing the page it is shown again on the same place, though I have not added it again.

Also, when I add another portlet, it is not shown.

Any Suggestion about what is going wrong here..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your server a local one (localhost)? And are there any other servers using the same Liferay Portal database?

Comment: No I have checked it. There is no other servers using Liferay Portal

Answer (score 0):

What account you use to delete the portlet? Try portal administrator instead of community administrator